# Pythonパッケージのライセンスを確認する方法

Tags: python, python3, pip

pip freezeでインストールされているパッケージの一覧を出力できますが、
各パッケージのライセンスを確認するコマンドはあるのでしょうか。
個別にWebで検索しなければいけないのでしょうか。

Comment: [pip-licenses](https://pypi.org/project/pip-licenses/) というパッケージがあります。

Comment: インストールして使用するとライセンスが表示されたのですが、以下のライセンスがUNKNOWNになっています。これはどういうことでしょうか。 mecab-python-windows  0.996.1    UNKNOWN　python-dotenv         0.9.1      UNKNOWN

Comment: `pip-licenses --from-classifier ...` とすると、python-dotenv の場合では `BSD License` と表示されます。`By default, this tool finds the license from package Metadata. However, depending on the type of package, it does not declare a license only in the Classifiers.`

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。コマンドで確認しました。ただ、mecab-python-windowsはUNKNOWNのままですね。

Comment: おそらく、mecab-python-windows パッケージでは METADATA ファイルにも Classifiers にもライセンスの記載がないのでしょうね(多少、妙な感じがしますが…)。

Comment: 載ってないのならしょうがないですね。コメントありがとうございます。

Comment: @user30138 一応、PyPI 上の mecab-python-windows にはライセンス表記があります: https://pypi.org/project/mecab-python-windows/

Comment: 参考: 本家 Stack Overflow での類似質問です: ["Can pip (or setuptools, distribute etc…) list the license used by each installed package?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19086030/5989200)

Comment: ３つのライセンスから選択できるんですね。選択できる条件は特に書いてないですけど、どれを選択してもいいということですよね。本家にも困っている人がいたんですね。ソースを動かしてみてライセンスがPythonで見られることはわかったんですけど、肝心のコメントは英語が読めないので何を書いているのかわかりませんでした。英語が読めないといろいろ不便ですね。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

個別には `pip show <パッケージ名>` で表示することができる場合があります。

また、[pip-licenses](https://pypi.org/project/pip-licenses/) というパッケージを使ってライセンスのみを一覧表示させることもできます。

もしライセンスが UNKNOWN と表示される場合、[ライセンスが書かれているフィールドが別にあるからかもしれません](http://raimon49.github.io/2018/02/18/check-license-as-unknown-with-pip-show-command.html)。その場合は

```
pip-licenses --from-classifier
```

を使うと表示される場合があります。詳しくは[ドキュメント](https://pypi.org/project/pip-licenses/#option-from-classifier)をご参照ください。

<sub>-- この投稿は [metropolis](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis) さんの[コメント1](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48650/python%E3%83%91%E3%83%83%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%81%AE%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%82%92%E7%A2%BA%E8%AA%8D%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95#comment50509_48650)、[2](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48650/python%E3%83%91%E3%83%83%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%81%AE%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%82%92%E7%A2%BA%E8%AA%8D%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95#comment50512_48650)を元にしつつ加筆編集したものです。</sub>